# ¿Cómo agregar mas de un número de proyectos agregados al ListView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, listview

Tengo un `WinForms` que consume varios Servicios Web.

En este contiene un `ListView` en el cual me da la opcion de seleccionar uno o varios proyectos el cual tienen que ser exportados.

Al seleccionar más de un proyecto, en el *output* siempre me aparece el primero que selecciono, no me aparecen todos los proyectos seleccionados en el `ListView`.

¿De qué forma puedo agregar esto? Será que el problema se encuentra en que tengo un `get/set` como `string`?

Aquí esta el código:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1;

}
string projectTitle { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    ProjectMetaData[] pr = GetProjectMetaData();

    foreach (ProjectMetaData proj in pr)
    {   
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(proj.ProjectID);
        listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string DateFormatStr = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt";
    string DateFormatFrom = "";
    byte[] MyBinFiles = GetResponse(projectTitle, DateFormatStr, DateFormatFrom);
}


private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    projectTitle = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

SeletedItems es un array, que contiene a todos los items seleccionados.

Para poder mostrar todos los seleccionados en algún output, podes recorrer la lista de items en SelectedItems e imprimir el Text, o asignar todos los Text a projectTitle, y hacer que project title sea una List o Array

```
List<string> projectTitles { get; set;}

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    projectTitles = new List<string>();
    foreach(ListViewItem item in this.listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        projectTitles.Add(item.Text);
    }
}
```

Y luego recorres la lista de projectTitles para hacer algo con esos datos.

```
private void Metodo() 
{
    foreach(string titulo in projectTitles)
    {
        System.Console.Println(titulo);
    }
}
```

Siempre podés obviar la variable de projectTitles y llamar al SelectedItems directamente

```
private void Metodo() 
{
    foreach(ListViewItem item in this.listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        System.Console.Println(item.Text);
    }
}
```

Siempre y cuando el método esté definido en el formulario.

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta. Al hacer el primer cambio del metodo ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged obtengo como error 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Mala mía. SelectedItems contiene un array con todos los ListViewItem seleccionados. El for debe recorrer la lista de ListViewItem, no de String. Ya modifiqué la respuesta.

Comment: gracias por modificar la respuesta. Ya no me da error pero ahora solo me exporta el ultimo proyecto selecionado

Comment: Hiciste el cambio de string projectTitle { get; set; } a List<string> projectTitles { get; set;}? Cómo lo estás llamando?

Comment: si ese fue el primer cambio que realize

Comment: Deberías poder recorrer esa lista, y deberían estar todos los títulos seleccionados ahí. Mientras estás en modo debug, podés hacer shift+F9 sobre una variable para ver lo que contiene.

Comment: segun lo que encontre en el debug, en la linea projectTitles.Add(item.Text); adentro del foreach siempre en item se pone en cero una vez que recorre la lista. cuando seleciono mas de un item, este se reinicia y pone el ultimo selecionado

Comment: Prueba usar el segundo método. Es probable que SelectedItemChanged se llame varias veces y sea difícil debugear. Igual falta el código donde llamas al projectTitles

Comment: una observación el control  `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` tiene una propiedad `MultiSelect` en `true`

Comment: En el ProjectMetaData hago la llamada a los proyectos y una vez que se afichan en el ListView intento exportarlos. El MultiSelect esta ya en true

Comment: otra cosa, me doy cuenta cuando hago un breakpoint en projectTitles.Add(item.Text); al seleccionar un proyecto, este se para en ese punto y no deja seleccionar mas, es ahi donde no se agregan mas proyectos a la lista.